# Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Firefox 3.6+, Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+

Tags: css

I am using this line of code in styles.css for full body

```
html {
  background-color: #E4E9FD;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(65deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
  min-height: 1000px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

and atom editor which i am using is giving this error - Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Firefox 3.6+, Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: i am getting a error in this, Missing vendor-prefixed CSS gradients for Firefox 3.6+, Old Webkit (Safari 4+, Chrome), Opera 11.1+.

Answer (score 1):

Add this property:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 25deg, #A683E3 50%, #E4E9FD 50%);
```